# Why is this game loop implementation getting a lower framerate than one that does more calculations per iteration?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt

I attempted to create my own implementation of a "game loop" using javax.swing and java.awt, but when my target fps was 60, I only got 49-52 fps on my implementation, while another implementation got 59-61 fps. Why would my implementation get a lower framerate if it's doing fewer calculations?

My Implementation:

```
public class MainContainer implements Runnable {

    public Thread thread;

    private final String title = "Window";

    private int width = 800, height = 600;
    private float scale = 1f;

    private GameWindow window;

    private final int FPS = 60;
    private final long NS_PER_UPDATE = (long)((1.0d/FPS) * 1000000000);
    private int current_total = 0;
    private boolean running;

    public MainContainer(){
        running = true;
        start();
    }

    public void start(){
        window = new GameWindow(this);
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.run();
    }
    public void stop(){

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long old = System.nanoTime();
        long counterOld = System.nanoTime();

        long missedTime;

        double frames = 0;

        long current;
        long delta;
        long counterDelta;

        while(running){
            current = System.nanoTime();
            delta = current - old;
            counterDelta = current - counterOld;

            if(counterDelta >= 1000000000){
                System.out.println(frames / (counterDelta/1000000000.0));
                frames = 0;
                counterOld = System.nanoTime();
            }

            if(delta >= NS_PER_UPDATE){
                render();
                missedTime = delta - NS_PER_UPDATE;
                old = System.nanoTime() - missedTime;
                frames++;
            }else{
                try {
                    thread.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void render(){
        window.update();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainContainer main = new MainContainer();
    }

    public int getWidth(){
        return width;
    }

    public int getHeight(){
        return height;
    }

    public float getScale(){
        return scale;
    }

    public void setScale(float s){
        scale = s;
    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }

    public GameWindow getWindow(){
        return window;
    }
}
```

Other Implementation:

```
public class MainContainer implements Runnable {

    public Thread thread;

    private final String title = "Window";

    private int width = 800, height = 600;
    private float scale = 1f;

    private final int FPS = 60;
    private final long NS_PER_UPDATE = (long)((1.0d/FPS) * 1000000000);
    private boolean running;

    private GameWindow window;

    public MainContainer(){
        running = true;
        start();
    }

    public void start(){
        window = new GameWindow(this);
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }
    public void stop(){

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        long unprocessedTime = 0;
        long frameTime = 0;

        double frames = 0;

        boolean render = false;

        long current;
        long delta;
        long old = System.nanoTime();

        while(running){
            current = System.nanoTime();
            delta = current - old;
            old = current;

            unprocessedTime += delta;
            frameTime += delta;

            while(unprocessedTime >= NS_PER_UPDATE){
                old = System.nanoTime();
                unprocessedTime -= NS_PER_UPDATE;
                render = true;

                if(frameTime >= 1000000000){
                    System.out.println(frames / (frameTime/1000000000.0));
                    frameTime = 0;
                    frames = 0;
                }
            }
            if(render){
                render();
                frames++;
                render = false;
            }else{
                try {
                    thread.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

    }

    public void render(){
        window.update();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainContainer main = new MainContainer();
    }

    public int getWidth(){
        return width;
    }

    public int getHeight(){
        return height;
    }

    public float getScale(){
        return scale;
    }

    public void setScale(float s){
        scale = s;
    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }

    public GameWindow getWindow(){
        return window;
    }
}
```

GameWindow Class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;

public class GameWindow {

    private JFrame frame;
    private BufferedImage image;
    private Canvas canvas;
    private BufferStrategy bs;
    private Graphics g;
    private boolean blue;
    private MainContainer mc;

    public GameWindow(MainContainer mc) {
        this.mc = mc;
        image = new BufferedImage(mc.getWidth(), mc.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        canvas = new Canvas();
        Dimension s = new Dimension((int)(mc.getWidth() * mc.getScale()), (int)(mc.getHeight() * mc.getScale()));
        canvas.setPreferredSize(s);
        canvas.setMinimumSize(s);
        canvas.setMaximumSize(s);

        frame = new JFrame(mc.getTitle());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        canvas.createBufferStrategy(2);
        bs = canvas.getBufferStrategy();
        g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    }

    public void update(){

        int[] p = ((DataBufferInt)(this.getImage().getRaster().getDataBuffer())).getData();
        for(int i = 0; i < p.length; i++){
            p[i] += i;
        }

        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), null);
        bs.show();
    }

    public BufferedImage getImage(){
        return image;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't mean to derail your approach but to me it seems over complicated in terms of keeping up with times and frames. Why not just set a timer that triggers your update method at an interval that satisfies your frame rate? Take a glance at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44478582/java-snake-game-avoiding-using-thread-sleep/44490317#44490317) and see if it looks applicable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in the "Other Implementation" its calculating the old time before the rendering process and in your implentation it is calculating it after the rendering process which make the value bigger because it is now also including the time it takes to render. So if you flip the code in your if statement around to look like this it will run at around 60 fps:

```
if(delta >= NS_PER_UPDATE){
    missedTime = delta - NS_PER_UPDATE;
    old = System.nanoTime() - missedTime;
    render();
    frames++;
}
```